# JSF Primefaces Y html input

Tags: java, html, jsf, primefaces

Por cuestiones de requerimiento, tengo que combinar componentes de primefaces y un input file en html puro. Ahora mi duda es, ¿puedo tener el input html dentro de un form JSF? Y que prácticamente toda la vista esté con PrimeFaces y desde un bean procesar el archivo a cargar con el componente input file. Ejemplo de lo que pretendo:

```
<p:panel header="Subir TXT" id="panelDwn" style="border: none;" >
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5" style="border: none;">
        <h:outputLabel style="color: #545454; font-size: 16px;" value="Seleccione el archivo a validar TXT:" />
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:panelGrid id="panelDes" columns="2" cellpadding="5" style="border: none;">
        <!-- INPUT FILE  HTML -->
        <input type="file" name="archivoupload"/>
        <h:outputLabel id="lblStatus" style="color: #545454; font-size: 16px;" value="#{uploadFileBean.status}" />                          
        <!--h:outputLabel style="color: #545454; font-size: 16px;" value="#{uploadFileBean.statusDownload}" /-->
    </h:panelGrid>
    <br />
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" style="border: none;">
        <p:commandButton styleClass="basicbtngobmx" value="Regresar" actionListener="#{captchaComponent.reset}" ajax="false" />
        <p:commandButton id="comdDwn" value="Descargar archivo" actionListener="#{uploadFileBean.resetValida}" ajax="false" disabled="#{uploadFileBean.status ==null or captchaComponent.statusBtnDescargarArchivo ==null}" update="fileUp">
            <p:fileDownload value="#{uploadFileBean.file}" ajax="false" />                           
        </p:commandButton>
    </h:panelGrid>                          
</p:panel>
```

Por detrás desde un bean invocar un servlet para subir y procesar el archivo y tener como salida un txt procesado. Solo tengo mi duda para esta funcionalidad.

En el código, trato de ejemplificar que el inputFile sera html y el resto componentes de primefaces.

Comment: Hola @Ventura. No entiendo bien tu pregunta. ¿Deseas procesar el formulario con un backing bean y solo la carga del archivo con un Servlet? ¿Tendrás dos formularios o uno solo? ¿Cómo es el flujo de tu aplicación en este caso?

Comment: Hola, tengo un formulario, en el básicamente se compone de el inputFile, html y un botón para cargar ese archivo seleccionado ( txt), y quiero que al presionar " Subir Archivo" , el formulario envíe el archivo al bean y el bean cargue el archivo  y este sea procesado y regrese la salida de igual forma en un txt. El flujo es: llego a la vista, me pide cargar un txt, selecciono el txt , presionar boton para inician carga, y que el  boton llame al bean para recibir el fichero txt  y hacer el proceso correspondiente. Y mi duda es, si es esto posible tener el  inputFile puramente en html

Comment: Comprendo. Tu formulario solo tiene el `<input type="file"/>` y un botón para enviar el archivo al servidor. Supongo que para este caso sería mejor utilizar un Servlet a utilizar JSF. Ten en cuenta que JSF y PrimeFaces harían el papel de generadores de HTML. Utiliza un `<form>` y no un `<h:form>`. Pero lo otro que me intriga es por qué no utilizar el componente `<h:inputFile>` que termina generando el `<input type="file">` que necesitas al final. Si aplicas JavaScript y CSS para decorarlo y agregarle funcionalidades, no tendrías ningún problema en generar dicho HTML desde JSF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es por requerimiento no hay de otra pero no recomiendo lo que comentas.

Pero para resolver lo que comentas utiliza esta etiqueta

```
  <f:view contentType="text/html">

         tu código html

 </f:view>
```

con esto jsf podrá compilar tu codigo html si problemas saludos

Answer (score 0):

Se puede realizar sin priblema alguno, lo que realiza jsf es generarte ese html y primefaces tambien te genera HTML, con jquery, yo optaria por realizarlo con jquery en lugar de html puro, ya que asi podrias darle un llamado ajax, si lo haces solo con html, tendras que enviar el formulario para ser procesado con el servlet.

Saludos